# Can't insert date with \maketitle (using llncs.cls)

Tags: titles, lncs

I'm just trying to write some notes on Overleaf using the llncs template (you can play with it [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/springer-lecture-notes-in-computer-science/kzwwpvhwnvfj#.V9s_rUYrKUk)), but when I put `\date{06 August 2016}` before `\maketitle`, nothing appears. Currently my notes begin with

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\begin{document}

\title{My Notes on Bla Bla}
\author{John Doe}
\institute{
\email{noreply@xyz.com}\\
}
\date{06 August 2016}
\maketitle
```

(I know my `\email` probably wasn't inserted correctly, but at this point I just need something that works)

All I want is something very basic like this:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `\date` does not form part of `\maketitle` under [`llncs`](http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs/lncs+authors?SGWID=0-40209-0-0-0). You'll either have to update the subsequent `\@maketitle` manually or perhaps patching it using something like [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox). However, an easier option is to just add it manually after a call to `\maketitle`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\title{My Notes on Bla Bla}
\author{John Doe}
\institute{
\email{noreply@xyz.com}\\
}
\date{06 August 2016}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\noindent
\makebox[\linewidth]{\small 06 August 2016}

\end{document}
```

---

Here would be a possible patch applied to `\@maketitle` using `etoolbox`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}% <cmd>
  {\end{center}}% <search>
  {\bigskip\small\@date
   \end{center}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

It inserts a gap and the `\date` supplied at the `\end{center}` - the end of `\@maketitle`.

Comment: thanks it worked! but for a long-term solution, could u plz also explain how I should update `\@maketitle`?

Comment: @ladiesman: Done.